# Where is K2 tag search page controller/view located?

Tags: k2, tags, seo

I want to exclude K2 tag pages from being indexed by search engine by adding

```
$document = & JFactory :: getDocument();
$document->setMetaData('robots', 'noindex');
```

to it's controller/view code. For some reason I can't find tag view or controller, from what I can gather it seems like it is merget with some other file.

There is `/components/com_k2/templates/default/tags.php` and `/components/com_k2/views/itemlist/tmpl/tag.php` but it doesn't seem like the thing I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Try in:

> components/com_k2/templates/default/item.php

Basically,  if you grep the code for the relevant language Field, **K2_TAGGED_UNDER**, you will see that there is relevant code in:

```
./templates/default/item.php:366:                 
<span><?php echo JText::_('K2_TAGGED_UNDER'); ?></span>

./templates/default/user.php:199:
<span><?php echo JText::_('K2_TAGGED_UNDER'); ?></span>

./templates/default/latest_item.php:104:
<span><?php echo JText::_('K2_TAGGED_UNDER'); ?></span>

./templates/default/category_item.php:193:
<span><?php echo JText::_('K2_TAGGED_UNDER'); ?></span>
```

Comment: I'm actually looking for a code that displays tag results (when you click on a tag and than you get all articles related to that tag) and not tags related to articles.

Comment: are you sure that this is not components/com_k2/templates/default/tag.php ? I found the relevant code there.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake. I had some caching problems and change didn't present it self so I figured I'm looking at the wrong place.